# VS 2010 Query Builder can't parse SCOPE_IDENTITY on Insert Statement

Tags: c#, sql, query-builder

I am using a SQL Data Source as such:

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="sds_sale" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestServerConnection %>"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Sale (transactionID, salePrice) VALUES (@transactionID,@salePrice)  SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="transactionID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="salePrice" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

The insert SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Sale (transactionID, salePrice) 
VALUES (@transactionID,@salePrice)  
SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I suppose to return the scope identity, but Query Builder say it can't parse the SQL statement.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider using a regular `SqlCommand`

Comment: But all my stuff are setup this way.

Comment: Does `@Identity` need to be sent in as an output parameter. Can't see you declaring it anywhere.

Comment: It's easy to get started with one of the many abstractions over SQL.  Like like Data Source, but also Linq2Sql or Entitiy Framework.  When you hit the abstraction's limitations, you have to work around them, or switch to the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace third line with this one:

```
SELECT @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

---

**Edit)**

you can see SQL profiler to see what statement send to Sql Server and you can debug it easier